# XPath-Python group text() under elements with the same name

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I need to extract all text under certain name of elements. But I need to group them as well. What will the XPath expression look like?

Example:

```
<root>
<list><t>t1</t><t>t1</t></list>
<list><t>t2</t><t>t2</t></list>
<list><t>t3</t><t>t3</t></list>
</root>
```

Expected a list result:

```
['t1t1', 't2t2', 't3t3']
```

I use python `lxml` package. I don't know how to group them.

```
s = """<root>
<list><t>t1</t><t>t1</t></list>
<list><t>t2</t><t>t2</t></list>
<list><t>t3</t><t>t3</t></list>
</root>"""
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.fromstring(s)
result = xml.xpath('//list//text()')
print(result)
```

My result:

```
['t1', 't1', 't2', 't2', 't3', 't3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below to get required output:

```
xml = etree.fromstring(s)
lists = xml.xpath('//list')
for item in lists:
    result = "".join([i for i in item.itertext()])
    print(result)
```